# Query from plugin that shows result on Map and in Attribute Table

Tags: postgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, attribute-table, features

I'd like to create a plugin that performs a static (no user input required) query that, based on a condition, selects all the features on the map and displays these in the attribute table.

I have the creation of the plugin itself under control.

However.

1) Querying the PostgreSQL DB with PyQGIS from the plugin and,

2) based on the result, select the features on the map (I'm not out to create a new layer),

3) and showing the selected features in the Attribute Table, is where I could use some hints.

Anyone that has experience with this or knows of one or more plugins where I can get some really good inspiration?